# Javascript AES with CryptoJS does not completely decrypt

Tags: aes

All information i got are encrypted `data` (AES) and a `key`. The data must be a URL. I 've tried so many code-snippets (from stackoverflow) and found one snippets that worked for me partially.

```
// Decode the base64 data so we can separate iv and crypt text.
var rawData = atob(data);
var iv = btoa(rawData.substring(0,16));
var crypttext = btoa(rawData.substring(16)); 

// Decrypt...
var plaintextArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
  {
    ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(crypttext),
    salt: ""
  },
  CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key),
  { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv) }
); 

// Convert hex string to ASCII.
function hex2a(hex) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}   

console.log(hex2a(plaintextArray.toString()));
```

The URL must be
`http://test-example.com/hjhdsdfuisd`
but the output is only
`-example.com/hjhdsdfuisd`.

I changed
`var crypttext = btoa(rawData.substring(16));`
to
`var crypttext = btoa(rawData);`
and got
`­ô#XÍäÜ7±H4-example.com/hjhdsdfuisd`.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Can your URL contain non-English characters?

Comment: No. There are only non-englisch characters.

Comment: Add `rawData` and the key in hex to the question. It looks like the first part was not encrypted.